# How to iterate over a JSON object and get properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I need to iterate over a JSON object using [the simple JSON Parser / builder](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)

I have this in a JSONNode via `JSONNode node = JSON.Parse(result);`.

Here's the JSON I get (of course it'll change a lot over time and it may have more or less properties):

```
{  
   "Nîddûrdy":{  
      "nb_players":"2",
      "width":"20",
      "height":"20",
      "ships":{  
         "aircraft_carrier":"10",
         "battleship":"0",
         "destroyer":"0",
         "submarine":"0",
         "torpilleur":"1"
      }
   },
   "Embers":{  
      "nb_players":"2",
      "width":"3",
      "height":"2",
      "ships":{  
         "aircraft_carrier":"0",
         "battleship":"0",
         "destroyer":"0",
         "submarine":"0",
         "torpilleur":"1"
      }
   },
   "Omyctudo":{  
      "nb_players":"2",
      "width":"3",
      "height":"2",
      "ships":{  
         "aircraft_carrier":"0",
         "battleship":"0",
         "destroyer":"0",
         "submarine":"0",
         "torpilleur":"1"
      }
   }
}
```

How would you do?

Comment: do you mean _iterating over the KeyValuePairs in the dictionary_?

Comment: Yes precisely, I'll update my question

Comment: i never ever have used SimpleJson nor Unity, but this seems to answer your question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/648066/how-to-get-the-keys-of-a-dictionary-.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution on my own: return the keys of the private variable `m_Dict`. Modify `SimpleJSON.cs` and add this property:

```
public class JSONClass : JSONNode, IEnumerable
{
    public Dictionary<string, JSONNode>.KeyCollection keys
    {
        get {
            return m_Dict.Keys;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a basic loop:

```
JSONClass j = (JSONClass)objJSON.AsObject ["games"];
foreach (string k in j.keys){
    Debug.Log (k);
    Debug.Log (j[k]);
}
```